# Python BeautifulSoup web scraping get last link in navigation

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get the number of pages (last page) from this page using beautifulsoup

I have coded the following to find the number of pages, but it does not work.

```
async def get_forum_threads(url, start_page=None):
    threads = []

    print('get forum threads')

    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    num_pages = 1
    try:
        num_pages = int(soup.find_all(
            'li', class_='pageNavNext')[-1].text.strip())
    except:
        pass
```

[image]

Comment: Found it: 
pageNumbers = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'PageNav'})['data-last']#Last page number is stored in data-last
print(pageNumbers)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

```
pageNumbers = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'PageNav'})['data-last']#Last page number is stored in data-last
print(pageNumbers)
```